# How do I redirect all file access request in a subfolder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

currently I have this

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TestRedirect",
    url: "Test/{*pathInfo}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I'm hoping all requests to access under Test is redirected to ~/Home/Index.
But unfortunately this doesn't work for file access such as /Test/index.html.
Only aspx files (like /Test/index.aspx) are redirected correctly though.

Can someone help me fix my routing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you want to make use of the pathinfo or ignore it and use /Home/Index?

Comment: @DaveA Actually I don't need to use it. I just grabbed it to work like a wild card or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is because static files are handled directly by IIS, and are not passed to ASP.NET for processing. The request is never reaching your application because IIS thinks it is a static file. If you are using integrated pipeline mode, simply register the following handler to ensure that all requests to `/Test` go through the managed pipeline and through your routing rules:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add 
            name="TestFolderHandler" 
            path="Test/*" 
            verb="GET" 
            type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
            preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding answer for reference.

Your code is fine, you just need to add

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```